# Solr not sorting copyField correctly

Tags: sorting, solr

I'm trying to get Solr to sort by Title, but I'm having no luck.

In my Schema I have the "title" field as text_general for searching, and then a "title_sort" field as a string for sorting. I've created a copyField that should be taking the "title" text_general field and putting it into the "title_sort" field as a string.

```
<fields>
  <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="title_sort" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />    
</fields>

<copyField source="title" dest="title_sort" />
```

When I run the sort query "title_sort desc" this is what I get back

```
title: Don’t Mind If I Do
title: Men Don't Run Marathons
title: Danny
```

Can a copyField not convert a text_general field into a string?

Comment: Can you please share your query that you are using for sort..

Comment: I'm a bit new to Solr, so let me know if this is what you're looking asking. When I query through the Solr admin panel, this is the URL string: http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&sort=title_sort+desc&wt=json&indent=true

Comment: Have you reindexed after adding the copyField instruction? (Solr will not go through all documents and update secondary fields) Set the `title_sort` field as stored and verify that you're getting the correct information there as well. Any `copyField` instruction happens before any fields are processed, so the type of the field doesn't affect the copyField instruction.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh that was exactly it. I'd been reloading the schema in the CoreAdmin panel, thinking that would make the changes. After deleting all the data, restarting solr and re-importing the data, it worked perfectly. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the help of [@MatsLindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh).

I'd been reloading the schema in the CoreAdmin panel, thinking that would make the changes. I had to reindex after adding the copyField instruction, as Solr will not go through all the documents and update secondary fields.